# Edit Unity InputAction interactions during runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am facing some issues with working with the "new" Unity input system. I am working on an FPS prototype, where the player can pick up different guns with different windup times. I do not want to keep track of how long the player has held the shoot key, as the Hold interaction can do that by itself.

Looking around Unity documentation, MS Intellisense suggestions, and Stackoverflow, I have not seen a single instance of something around the lines of "Override interactions of InputAction". It is simply something not being talked about. Should I take that as a red flag for what I am doing is wrong? Probably.

I can see the `interactions` field for an InputAction, but it is marked with the `readonly` keyword. There is no internal setter for it either. Otherwise, the solution would be trivial, though unusual to the Unity™ way.

```cs
float duration = 0.04f;
controls.Main.Shoot.interactions = $"Hold(duration={duration})";
// Error: "Interactions" is readonly
```

Is there really not a way to edit the interactions for an `InputAction` during runtime with code?

Comment: Haven't messed with this but [this 2 year old thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-adjust-hold-time-via-script.769904/) suggests writing a custom interaction to read the duration. I hope things have improved for the better though!

Comment: using command pattern and go